What is the proper way to create an internal link in wikitext?
Our goal is to create an internal-facing hyper link such that....


the text people see with their eyes says "hot dogs"

The page on mathematical strict total orderings is the destination page that people are taken to after they click on "hot dogs"







Here is some broken code that is not working very well.
==Mathematics==   

In an inequality, the less-than sign and greater-than sign always "point" to the smaller number. Put another way, the "jaws" (the wider section of the symbol) always direct to the larger number.   

1. [[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_and_non-strict_total_orders|hot dogs]]

2. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_and_non-strict_total_ordersTotal_order#Strict_and_non-strict_total_orders|hot dogs]

In mathematics, the less-than-sign is somtimes used to represent a [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_and_non-strict_total_orders|strict total ordering]. However, a more commonly used symbol for strict total orderings is '''≺''', which is known in Unicode character set as the 'PRECEDES' character or U+227A.




The incorrect code I provided produced a hyperlink having the flavor text dogs instead of hot dogs
Also, there is some issue with square brackets [] being visible in the rendered HTML page.

wikitext is a language used for Wikipedia.
wikitext is also known as wiki markup or wikicode.

Perhaps it would be prudent to propose a new site for wikitext on Area 51, but I do not have the clout to make new proposals these days.
 

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about web applications within the scope defined in the Help Center.

This is what Mediawiki Help:Links would suggest for internal links, calling it "Piped links":
==Mathematics==   

In an inequality, the less-than sign and greater-than sign always "point" to the smaller number. Put another way, the "jaws" (the wider section of the symbol) always direct to the larger number.   

1. [[Total order#Strict and non-strict total orders|hot dogs]]

2. [[Total order#Strict and non-strict total orders|hot dogs]]

In mathematics, the less-than-sign is somtimes used to represent a [[Total order#Strict and non-strict total orders|strict total ordering]]. However, a more commonly used symbol for strict total orderings is '''≺''', which is known in Unicode character set as the 'PRECEDES' character or U+227A.

